# How to write a batch file to find a file and copy name then display?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to find a specific file that named `~test.c` for example, there are filenames like this:

```
main.c  
2019_test.c  
setting.c
```

Then I want to copy file name `2019_test.c` then echo and it should work by using a batch file (batch script). How to do that?

I wrote this code but get stuck. It doesn't work.

```
@echo off  
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion  
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /i "_test"') do echo %%a  
pause
```

Comment: `for %%a in (*_test.c) do echo %%a`

Comment: To make sure that you're checking all filenames, including `dir` may be useful. `For /F "EOL=|Delims=" %%# In ('Dir /B/S/A-D "\*._test.c" 2^>NUL^|FindStr /I "\.c$"')Do @Echo %%#` Alternatively, you could use `where.exe` instead, `For /F "EOL=|Delims=" %%# In ('Where /R \ "*._test.c" 2^>NUL')Do @Echo %%#`. These examples will search only within one, (the current), drive so you'd need to extend the code when searching within more that one drive.

Comment: @Compo Thank you, It's really helpful.